# Opera Bug When Charging A Page

Tags: refresh, opera, page-refresh, pageload

I have a bug which started fex days ago :
you can see an image of the bug [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZB6z.png)

It's like my browser needs to be refreashed (sometimes 5 times in a row)

I've tried to clean with cc cleaner and I don't have any malwares "active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens to you, it's the VPN :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).